# Angular material extension link preview error

Tags: angular, angular-material

Trying to implement [@angular-material-extensions/link-preview](https://angular-material-extensions.github.io/link-preview/doc/). When I try to import module it triggers following error.

```
import { MatLinkPreviewModule } from '@angular-material-extensions/link-preview';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    .....
    MatLinkPreviewModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  ......
```

> ERROR in Failed to compile entry-point
> @angular-material-extensions/link-preview (es2015 as esm2015) due to
> compilation errors:

From documentation I got the module should map `umd.js` file. But not sure how that works. Can anyone help me about the work around for the issue. I might be missing something.

[image: Map module from node_modules]